# In Spring what is the difference between @Profile and @ActiveProfiles

Tags: java, spring

What is the difference between using @Profile and @ActiveProfiles on a Spring Test configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
@ActiveProfiles("unittest") 
static class ContextConfiguration {
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
@Profile("unittest") 
static class ContextConfiguration {
```

Comment: `@ActiveProfiles` is part of `org.springframework.test`,  Im assuming its used to loading profiles during testing.  `@Profile`  is used for defining/naming profile specific configurations.  I've never used `@ActiveProfiles` so this is just my logical guess.

Comment: I came across this answer here which seems to generally answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/a/27216503/277023

Comment: Even if you aren't using `@Profile`, `@ActiveProfiles("test")` can be useful to make `src\test\resources\application-test.properties` active in JUnit tests. Note that eclipse 'Run As->JUnit test' behaves differently than `mvn test` as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60296719/4505142

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In short, `@Profile` defines a profile like a Debug profile and a Production profile etc... However `@ActiveProfiles` comes into picture in case of an [`ApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) and defines which profiles should be active if respective `ApplicationContext` is being used.

As mentioned in JavaDoc of Spring official website:

[@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

> A profile is a named logical grouping that may be activated programmatically via ConfigurableEnvironment.setActiveProfiles(java.lang.String...) or declaratively by setting the spring.profiles.active property as a JVM system property, as an environment variable, or as a Servlet context parameter in web.xml for web applications. Profiles may also be activated declaratively in integration tests via the @ActiveProfiles annotation.

[@ActiveProfiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html)

> ActiveProfiles is a class-level annotation that is used to declare which active bean definition profiles should be used when loading an ApplicationContext for test classes.

Also, you can [see here for more information about @Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Answer (score 30):

Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration.

Any `@Component` or `@Configuration` can be marked with `@Profile` to limit when it is loaded which means that component or configuration will be loaded in the application context only when the active profiles is same as the profile mapped to a component.

To mark a profile active, `spring.profiles.active` property must be set in `application.properties` or given as an VM argument as `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

While writing Junit, you would want to activate some profile so as to load the required configuration or Component. Same can be achieved by using `@ActiveProfile` annotation.

Consider a configuration class which is mapped to profile `dev`

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("mnrpass");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
}
```

Consider a configuration class which is mapped to profile `prod`

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/prod");
        ds.setUsername("dbuser");
        ds.setPassword("prodPass123");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
}
```

So, if you want to run your junit test cases in `dev` profile then you have to use the `@ActiveProfile('dev')` annotation. This will load the DataSourceConfig bean defined in dev profile.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class Tests{

    // Junit Test cases will use the 'dev' profile DataSource Configuration

}
```

> Conclusion

`@Profile` is used to map a class to a profile

`@ActiveProfile` is used to activate a particular profile(s) during junit test class execution

Answer (score 7):

> Any @Component or @Configuration can be marked with **@Profile** to limit
>   when it is loaded.

You define `@Profile` for your:

1. classes -directly or indirectly- annotated with `@Component`, including `@Configuration` classes
2. methods annotated with `@Bean`

Then while testing, you choose which profile(s) you want by specifying them in `@ActiveProfiles`.

> **ActiveProfiles** is a class-level annotation that is used to declare
>   which active bean definition profiles should be used when loading an
>   ApplicationContext for **test** classes.

It has no effect if used outside of the test context.

### Summary

You assign profile to your components with `@Profile`; while testing select them with `@ActiveProfiles`, while developing select them with `spring.profiles.active` property.

Answer (score 3):

`@Profile` is used to define different `@Bean` definitions for different contexts, e.g:

```
public class BeanConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Profile({"local", "dev", "ci-dev", "homolog"})
    public SomeHttpClientBean adyenClientFactorySandbox() {
        return SomeHttpClientBean.builder()
            .url("https://test.example.com")
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("prod")
    public SomeHttpClientBean adyenClientFactorySandbox() {
        return SomeHttpClientBean.builder()
            .url("https://production.example.com")
            .build();
    }
}
```

Once you have that configuration, when starting your application, all you need to do is set which profile is active, either by `spring.profiles.active` property or by annotating a class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles("ci-dev")
public class SpringBootTestBase {
    @Test
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- with `@Profile` annotation you set condition to your bean definition, which impacts create or not create this bean in your spring context depending on current active profiles. Example from JavaDoc:

  `@Profile({"p1", "!p2"}` -  registration will occur if profile 'p1' is active
  **or** if profile 'p2' is **not** active.
- with `@ActiveProfiles` you set current active profiles. Example:

  `@ActiveProfiles({"p2","p3"})` bean with annotation `@Profile({"p1", "!p2"}` will **not** be created.

  `@ActiveProfiles({"p3"})` bean with annotation `@Profile({"p1", "!p2"}` will be created.

  `@ActiveProfiles({"p1"})` bean with annotation `@Profile({"p1", "!p2"}` will be created.

Answer (score 2):

`@Profile` is used when **declaring** a bean or configuration. `@Profile` declares which profile the bean or configuration belongs to.

`@ActiveProfiles` is used only from tests that are **consuming** a bean or configuration to **enable** one or more profiles.

When `@ActiveProfiles` is specified, it causes the Spring Context to check whether a bean or configuration is annotated with `@Profile`. If so, that bean or configuration is only loaded if the profile in `@ActiveProfiles` matches the profile rule in the bean's `@Profile` annotation.